# Display Page Properties on Wiki Page - Wiki Page Library

Tags: 2013, wiki-pages

I've seen several questions regarding this topic, but there are no answers (at least where I've looked). I have a wiki page library (SP 2013) with several page properties (i.e. - statuses, dates, category). I'd like to display some of those properties on the wiki page but I haven't encountered an efficient way of doing that.

We update some of the properties frequently and display them on the wiki page, so we're doing redundant work of updating the properties and then updating the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated and again, I apologize if this question has already been asked...couldn't find a similar question that was still current.

Thank you!